# Add item to select box with an Eloquent collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a select box on a form which uses data that is listed from an Eloquent model (Laravel 4):

```
$campuses = Campus::lists('name', 'id');
```

And the form:

```
{{ Form::select('campus_id', $campuses) }}
```

However, I would like to have the first option on the form be `Select...` so that when the user has not selected an option yet, the first option does not become the default.

How can I prepend another option to the beginning of the Eloquent collection?

I've tried something like:

```
$campuses = array('Select...') . Campus::lists('name', 'id');
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could also do

```
$campuses = array('' => 'Select...') + Campus::lists('name', 'id');
```

This is the way I use it, sum 2 arrays

Comment: I think lists method has been removed in favour of `pluck()`

Answer (score 3):

You can merge 2 arrays with `array_merge` function.

So, the answer will be

`$campuses = array_merge(array('Select...'), Campus::lists('name', 'id'));`

Comment: in later version, we need to add ->all() after the ::list() argument. Because lists no longer return array, and adding ->all() will return them in array so we can use array_merge.