# Laravel lists function prepend value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

Laravel `lists` function used to return an array so I [could prepend a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606181/add-item-to-select-box-with-an-eloquent-collection). However it now is an object. What I would like to do is generate a list for a dropdown but add an extra value to the front that says something like:

```
['select a value.', '0']
```

How should I prepend data to the new Laravel `lists` function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`lists()` returns a `Collection` object. To add an item to the beginning of the collection, you can use the `prepend` method:

```
$statusCollection = \App\Status::lists('name', 'id');
$statusCollection->prepend('select a value', 0);
```

Make sure you pass in a non-null key as the second parameter to `prepend`, otherwise this method will end up renumbering your numeric keys. If you don't provide a key, or pass in null, the underlying logic will use `array_shift`, which will renumber the keys. If you do provide a key, it uses an array union (`+`), which should preserve the keys.

For another option, you can get the underlying item array using the `all()` method and just do what you did before:

```
$statusCollection = \App\Status::lists('name', 'id');
$statusArray = $statusCollection->all();

// if you want to renumber the keys, use array_shift
array_unshift($statusArray, 'select a value');

// if you want to preserve the keys, use an array union
$statusArray = [0 => 'select a value'] + $statusArray;
```

Comment: lists('name','id')->prepend('Select an option'); is reindexing my collection and i'm losing the original id value. Any suggestions?

Comment: @zeros-ones I have updated my answer. Basically, just make sure you provide a non-null key parameter: `lists('name','id')->prepend('Select an option', 0);`

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok with the numeric keys being reindexed, then the accepted answer of using `array_unshift()` works. If you want to maintain the original numeric keys (for example, if the keys correspond to the id of your table entries), then you could do as follows:

```
$statusCollection = \App\Status::lists('name', 'id');
$statusArray = $statusCollection->all();
$finalArray = array('0' => 'Select a value') + $statusArray;
```